# What does it mean when last_analyzed and stale_stats is null

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle11g, database-performance

We are currently running Oracle 11g and I am looking into if we need to run statistics after a large import.  We have statistics_level set to 'TYPICAL'.  Based on this I'm thinking that we do NOT need to update statistics:

> Starting with Oracle Database 11g, the MONITORING and NOMONITORING
>   keywords have been deprecated and statistics are collected
>   automatically.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables005.htm

However, after creating my database and running my modest import (100's of thousands to millions of records in a handful of tables and the creation of a number of indexes) all of the tables affected by the import show null for last_analyzed and stale_stats using the query below.

```
select 
    table_name, 
    stale_stats, 
    last_analyzed
from 
    dba_tab_statistics
 where 
    owner = 'MY_SCHEMA'
order by 
    last_analyzed desc, table_name asc
;
```

Should I expect certain queries to have poor performance in this state?

Should I expect the statistics to eventually run and last_analyzed and stale_stats to eventually be populated (the documentation suggests that these values are updated about every three hours by default)?

It has been my experience that for moderately sized databases (tables with millions of records and less than 10's of millions of records) that mucking around with stats is not necessary and generally causes more problems than it solves. Is this generally the case?

*** * * NOTES ON OUR RESOLUTION * * ***

We were using this:

```
analyze table my_table compute statistics
```

We switched to this:

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('MY_SCHEMA', 'MY_TABLE');
```

The analyze table statement took about 1:30 minutes in one environment and about 15:00 - 20:00 minutes in the second environment.

The gather_table_stats statement took about 0:30 to 1:00 minutes in both of the two instances we were able to examine.

Our plan moving forward is to switch our analyze table statements to gather_table_stats calls.

Comment: maybe the topic will be useful. AskTom. Automated Statistics Collection https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1133388300346992024

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STATISTICS_LEVEL and gathering table/index statistics are entirely different things. STATISTICS_LEVEL affect if row source statistics are gathered during command execution. So then you're able to compare the optimizer estimates and actual values for each step in display cursor.

So table/index statistics are used for execution plan optimization and STATISTICS_LEVEL for gathering execution statistics when execution plan is being executed and it's mostly for diagnostic purposes.

When `last_analyzed` is null it means that table statistics hasn't been gathered yet.

`stale_stats` says whether the stats are considered fresh or stale, or if the stats will be gathered automatically next time or not. The default settings is 10 percent. If you gather table statistics and then insert/update/delete less than 10 percent of rows the statistics is considered fresh. When you reach 10 percent of modified rows they become stale.

Oracle by default gathers table/index statistics automatically during maintenance window which is automatically configured when a database is created. It's usually reconfigured by DBAs if there are specific requirements.

Regarding the `STATISTICS_LEVEL`, with default value `TYPICAL` it looks like this:

```
HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> select * from dual;

D
-
X
HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(NULL, NULL, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  a5ks9fhw2v9s1, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select * from dual

Plan hash value: 272002086

-------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | E-Rows |
-------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |        |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |      1 |
-------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - Warning: basic plan statistics not available. These are only collected when:
       * hint 'gather_plan_statistics' is used for the statement or
       * parameter 'statistics_level' is set to 'ALL', at session or system level
```

We don't see anything more than estimated number of rows. If you set `ALTER SESSION SET statistics_level = ALL` then

```
HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> ALTER SESSION SET statistics_level = ALL;
HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> select * from dual;

D
-
X
HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(NULL, NULL, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  a5ks9fhw2v9s1, child number 1
-------------------------------------
select * from dual

Plan hash value: 272002086

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now we see also the actual number of rows and time taken to execute each step as well as number of consistent reads (buffers column).

With more complex queries you will get much more information than this. You should check the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xplan.htm

Also be aware that the statistics sampling is not done with every row but by default every 128 rows (can be changed using undocumented `_rowsource_statistics_sampfreq` parameter)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what is the bottom line: can I just let Oracle do it's thing in the background or do I need to worry about doing things like analyze table like in the good old days?

Comment: I added one more paragraph to the answer. There is default maintenance window configuration for newly created database so statistics will be collected periodically according the rules I described above. We usually care about statistics when we rapidly change table content which can lead to execution plan changes and sub-optimal execution plans. In most cases the periodical gathering is enough in some is much better to gather or compute statistics manually. You should know your data and requirements, Gathering statistics, especially histograms could take much time and resources for big tables.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the issue we are looking at: "Gathering statistics, especially histograms could take much time and resources for big tables." We have some large tables and our automated process analyzes these tables after doing a "bulk" update.  However, some bulk updates only include a handful of records.  In these cases there is a user expectation that the upload should not take very long (I'm just inserting a few records, this shouldn't take long).  When analyze is run after these small uploads it takes a long time and fails this expectation.  So...

Comment: It sounds like the best solution would be to run the analyze only after large "bulk" updates.  A slightly less optimal solution would be to run analyze once after our initial large upload (assuming that the data in the database at that point are representative of the larger data set.

Comment: If you have really large loads or incremental updates and you know your data sometimes it's better way to compute statistics on your own and set them manually instead of large full table scans or even worse histogram sorts. Or you can lower the sample take for calculating statistics on big tables (but there can be issues if the data isn't evenly distributed). Here is link as an inspiration how to do it: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/fake-histograms. There is really lot already been written about gathering statistics so you can google around and decide what suits you the best.

Answer (score 2):

(Husqvik thoroughly explained the meaning of the columns and parameters, this answer only addresses how to gather statistics.)

Statistics should be manually gathered after any significant<sup>*</sup> change to a table.  Oracle has a great default, automatic statistics gathering processes since 11g.  But even with that new system there are still at least two good reasons to manually gather statistics.  The default statistics gathering auto-task is normally meant for slowly-changing OLTP tables, not fast-changing data warehouse tables.

1. **Significant data changes can easily lead to significant performance problems.**  If the tables are going to be used right after they are loaded then they need good statistics immediately.

   A common problem in ETL processes is when tables go from 1 row to a million rows.  The optimizer thinks there is still only one row in large tables and uses lots of nested loops joins instead of hash joins.  Those algorithms work well in different contexts; without good statistics Oracle does not know the correct context.

   It's important to note that a NULL `LAST_ANALYZED` is not the worst case scenario.  When there are no statistics at all, Oracle will use dynamic sampling to generate quick statistics estimates.  The worst case is when the statistics job ran last night when the table is empty; Oracle thinks it has good statistics when it really doesn't.
2. **The statistics auto-task may not be able to keep up with large changes.**  The statistics auto-task is a low-priority, single-threaded process.  If there are too many large tables left to the automatic process it may not be able to process them during the maintenance window.

---

The bad news is that developers can't ignore optimizer statistics.  The DBAs can't just handle it later.  It might help to read some of the chapters from the manuals, such as [Managing Optimizer Statistics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16638/stats.htm).

The goods news is that Oracle 11g finally has nice default settings.  You usually don't need to muck around with the parameters.  In most cases there's a simple rule to follow: if the table changed significantly, run this:

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME');
```

---

*: "Significant" is a subjective word.  A change is normally significant in terms of relative size, not absolute.  Adding one million rows to a table is significant if the table currently has one row, but not if the table has a billion rows.